# How to install & run colororacle?

Tags: d3.js, jar, data-visualization

[ColorOracle](http://colororacle.org) is a free color blindness simulator for Window, Mac and Linux. It help to check an UI Color Design for the Color Vision Impaired people.

Its executable file is a .jar. **How to install an run colorOracle ?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On linux, via terminal :**

```
cd ./path/to/myfolder
mkdir colorOracle
curl -o ./colorOracle/ColorOracleJar.zip -C - http://colororacle.org/ColorOracleJar.zip
unzip -n ./colororacle/ColorOracleJar.zip -d ./colorOracle
chmod a+x ./colorOracle/ColorOracle.jar
./colorOracle/ColorOracle.jar
```

For other OS, see http://colororacle.org

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution for the run part is to use Java `-jar`option :

```
java -jar ./colorOracle/ColorOracle.jar
```

Excerpt from the `man java` page:

> -jar
>
> ```
>     Execute a program encapsulated in a JAR file. The first argument is the 
>     name of a JAR file instead of a startup class name. 
>     […./colorOracle/ColorOracle.jar].
>     See the Jar tool reference page 
>     and the Jar trail of the Java Tutorial @
>     http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jar for information about 
>     working with Jar files and Jar-file manifests.
> ```